# Get data from SFLOW RT

Tags: python, mininet

I want to make a dikstra algorithm which is aware with congestion

I'm monitoring get values from `http://localhost:8008/metric/ALL/flows/json`

Here's my code:

```
def checkCost(self):
    # flag=1
    while (1):
    #print "ok haha"
        url = 'http://localhost:8008/metric/ALL/flows/json'
        r = requests.get(url)
        vals = r.json()
        valueNumber=0
        for v in vals:
            mname  = v["metricValue"]
            message = '%s  \n' % (mname)
            valueNumber=float(message)
            # print message
```

And my topology:

[image]

I have weight values for every path:

```
s1 -> s2 = 2
s1 -> s3 = 2
s1 -> s4 = 1
s2 -> s3 = 2
s3 -> s4 = 2
s4 -> s5 = 1
```

```
def dijalg(self,G,source,wG=None,huge=1e30000):
    dist={}
    pred={}
    Q = priorityDictionary()
    Q[source] = 0
    #print (G.edge)
    if wG == None:
        for u in G.edge:
            dist[u]={}
            for v in G.edge:
                #print type(v)
                #print G.has_edge
                if G.has_edge(u,v):
                    if (u==1):
                        if (v==2):
                            dist[u][v] = 2
                        elif (v==3):
                            dist[u][v] = 2
                        elif (v==4):
                            dist[u][v] = 1
                    if (u==2):
                        if (v==1):
                            dist[u][v] = 2
                        elif (v==3):
                            dist[u][v] = 2
                    if (u==3):
                        if (v==1):
                            dist[u][v] = 2
                        elif (v==4):
                            dist[u][v] = 1
                    if (u==4):
                        if (v==1):
                            dist[u][v] = 1
                        elif (v==3):
                            dist[u][v] = 1
                        elif (v==5):
                            dist[u][v] = 1
                    if (u==5):
                        if (v==4):
                            dist[u][v] = 1
                else:
                    dist[u][v]=huge
            dist[u][u]=0
```

If the value of valuenumber is greater than 1000000kbit the cost will be +10 and they'll search for another path.

For example

`s4 -> s1` is more than 1000000kbit
So if s5 needs to path to s1 it'd want to do s5->s4->s1. But if I have a condition where value of `valuenumber > 1000000kbit` the weighted cost will go up by 10 so cost in s4 -> s1 will actually be 11 and s5 will search for another path.

I'm confused about how to do this test on value number, can anyone help?

Comment: Please read your message again and fix grammar and typos. when you ask questions you should try to write it in correct English, with proper capitalization and using the power of [Markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to make the question easy to read.

Comment: Hi there! I edited your post to tidy up the language and formatting, making it easier to read. As mnencia said, this is important for making your question understandable. Feel free to perform more edits if you think there's further improvements to be made.